# Javascript post filtering system not functioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a simple filtering systemt that would hide posts that do not have the same id as the `li`'s under the `navig` class. To achieve this I am looping through all `.article li`'s and checking what's their `id`.

Example:

1. click on `li` with `id="health"`
2. Article 2 disappears

Thank you!

HTML:

```
<ul class="navig">
    <li id="health">Health</li>
    <li id="ASD">ASD</li>
</ul>

<br>

<ul class="article">
    <li id="health">Article 1</li> <br>
    <li id="ASD">Article 2</li> <br>
    <li id="health">Article 3</li> 
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
$('.navig li').onclick(function () {
    $id = this.id;
    $('.article li').each(function() {
        if ($id != this.id) {
            $('.article li').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You can't have same ID's on page.

Comment: If you want to avoid collision between css classes (as you cannot use id), html5 allows you to define your own attributes, but they have to begin with data- . So if you simply switch from <li id="id"  to <li data-id="id" that will solve your problem and you won't have to take special care with css classes that are used for layout design purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fundamental problem is your HTML is invalid. You can't use the same `id` value on more than one element. Separately, you've used `onclick` where you would want to use `click`.

I'd probably use a `data-article-id` attribute on the navigation `li` instead, like this:

For example: [Live copy](http://jsbin.com/ritimidi/1) ([source](http://jsbin.com/ritimidi/1/edit))

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Testing</title>
</head>
<body>
  <ul class="navig">
    <li data-article-id="health">Health</li>
    <li data-article-id="ASD">ASD</li>
  </ul>

  <br>

  <ul class="article">
    <li id="health">Health Article</li>
    <li id="ASD">ASD Article</li>
  </ul>

  <script>

    $('.navig li').click(function () {
      var articleId = $(this).attr("data-article-id");
      alert(articleId);
      var articles = $(".article li");
      articles.not("#" + articleId).hide();
      $("#" + articleId).show();
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

You'll want to do something to hide the articles (or show a default one) when the page loads, etc.; I'll leave that as an exercise for you. :-)

---

Side note: `br` elements cannot be children of `ul` elements, I've removed the ones from the `articles` list.

Comment: Still got an issue ;) with ids and you copied the invalid html/

Comment: @epascarello: I didn't notice the second health article until doing the live example. (The OP had `id="health"` not only on a navigation item and an article item, but also on a *second* article item.) *sigh* And there there were those `br` elements...

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.navig li').onclick(function () {  <-- not valid jquery
```

There is no onclick method in jQuery...there is `.click(function(){})` or `on("click", function(){})`

second porblem, ids need to be singular. They can not be repeated. Use a data attribute [and br's can not be children of ul]

```
<ul class="navig">
    <li id="health">Health</li>
    <li id="ASD">ASD</li>
</ul>

<br>

<ul class="article">
    <li data-id="health">Article 1</li> 
    <li data-id="ASD">Article 2</li>
    <li data-id="health">Article 3</li> 
</ul>
```

and script

```
$('.navig li').on("click", function() {
   var id = this.id;
   $(".article li").hide().filter('[data-id="' + id + '"]').show();
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q8SCF/